# Not able to update angular icon in PWA android app splash screen

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, splash-screen, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a progressive web app using angular 7 and I am facing the issue of PWA application splash screen icon in android device. I have updated all sizes icon of suggested in manifest.json

But still, the splash screen icon shows the angular icon instead of the provided icon.

icon-72x72.png
icon-96x96.png
icon-128x128.png
icon-144x144.png
icon-152x152.png
icon-192x192.png
icon-384x384.png
icon-512x512.png

I have added above sizes in the manifest.json

Comment: Can you add your manifest.json file?

Comment: Perhaps ask someone else new to check your PWA on their device and they see the same? Just to make sure you do not have anything cached.

Comment: Thanks jess and Mathias. I got solution using clear mobile chrome storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you clear the cache for the browser you are testing with.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. Yes, I have removed cache file storage from the mobile chrome and its work as expected.

Comment: Excellent, could you flag this as the answer so others can easily see the solution

Comment: Also do you have any idea on how to add a custom splash screen in my angular PWA, instead of just showing that icon on screen.

Comment: @ASR you can probably make your own to show after the one with the logo, but sorry  I know of no way to change that. Most people would rather not see a splash screen though but get straight to the app.